# Groupby and collect_list maintaining order based on another column in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe like this,

```
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|   Name   |  dateCol1  |  dateCol2  |  dateCol3  |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
| user1    | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-10 | 2018-01-01 |
| user1    | 2018-01-11 | 2018-01-20 | 2018-01-01 |
| user2    | 2018-01-11 | 2018-01-20 | 2018-01-11 |
| user1    | 2019-01-21 | 2018-01-30 | 2018-01-01 |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I want to groupby this dataset on keys, dateCol1 and dateCol2 and so a collect_list over the column Name. For that I'm using the code,

```
spark_df.groupBy('dateCol1', 'dateCol2').agg(F.collect_list('Name'))
```

While collecting the column to list, I also want to maintain the order of the values based on the column dateCol3.

For instance, I want to make sure that for the `dateCol1 == '2018-01-11'` and `dateCol2 == '2018-01-20'`, collecting to list I will always get `[user1, user2]` (based on the order of dateCol3).

The required output for the dataframe is,

```
+------------+------------+----------------+
|  dateCol1  |  dateCol2  |    List        |
+------------+------------+----------------+
| 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-10 | [user1]        |
| 2018-01-11 | 2018-01-20 | [user1, user2] |
| 2019-01-21 | 2018-01-30 | [user1]        |
+------------+------------+----------------+
```

collect_list won't maintain order by default, How make sure that the collected list is ordered based on another external column from the dataframe?

Comment: @YOLO, I want to maintain the order while list is created by collect_list based on dateCol3. Sorting the dataframe based on dateCol3 and then collect_list was not conistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
spark_df.orderBy('dateCol3', ascending=True).groupBy('dateCol1', 'dateCol2').agg(F.collect_list('Name'))
```

Alternatively, although it would be a bit of overkill you can use windowing:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window as w

spark_df.select('dateCol1', 'dateCol2', F.collect_list('Name').over(w.partitionBy(['dateCol1','dateCol2']).orderBy(F.col('dateCol3'))).alias('Name')).distinct()
```

Comment: I was looking for the window based approach. I guess the partition and ordering based on dateCol3 will make sure the list in collected in order. Doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's the idea.

Comment: The solution is almost correct, but getting additional rows. distinct won't drop some rows. I wonder whether I can do the partition and order over collect_list in a groupBy. Other wise, I have to again use a window and dropDuplicates over the keys maintaining order

Comment: Yes, you can put it in ```.groupBy(...)``` after ```.select(...)``` - that will also do. However I would assume ```distinct()``` should do for you, unless you have some more columns to add there and/or some more transformation